# Unfold a 2D array spiral in C#

Tags: c#, array, linq

The purpose of this function is to turn a 2D array of sorts into a single-dimensional array by reading it in a spiral fashion.

In the array:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

if it's a clockwise spiral it will read `1,2,3,6,9,8,7,4,5`first going right, then down, then left and then up repeatedly until it's at a dead end.

The code I wrote to perform this function seems to work properly from my tests, and only have a few pet peeves with it.

- Uses helper boolean 2D array wasting memory
- Duplicate code for clockwise and counterclockwise operation just for the different order

The purpose of this code review is:

- Get feedback on my coding style (including naming and structure)
- Inspiration for better cleaner methods (preferably using Linq queries)
- Have my code criticized from every aspect

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace testIEnum
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[][] matrix = new int[][] {
                new int[] {01,02,03,04,05,06},
                new int[] {07,08,09,10,11,12},
                new int[] {13,14,15,16,17,18},
                new int[] {19,20,21,22,23,24}
            };


            var unfolded = matrix.toUnfoldedSpiral(Direction.clockwise, StartPoint.topLeft);
            unfolded.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
            while (true) ;
        }

        public enum StartPoint
        {
            topLeft,
            topRight,
            bottomRight,
            bottomLeft

        };

        public enum Direction
        {
            clockwise,
            counterclockwise
        };

        public struct Point
        {
            public int X;
            public int Y;
            public static bool operator ==(Point p1,Point p2)
            {
                return p1.X == p2.X && p1.Y == p2.Y;
            }
            public static bool operator !=(Point p1, Point p2)
            {
                return p1.X != p2.X || p1.Y != p2.Y;
            }
        }

        public static IEnumerable<TSource> toUnfoldedSpiral<TSource>(this TSource[][] input, Direction dir, StartPoint point)
        {
            bool[][] visitedTable = input.Select(n => n.Select(m => false).ToArray()).ToArray();
            //create helper boolean 2d array to make sure I dont go over the same element twice
            var pointConvertion = new Dictionary<StartPoint, Point>()
            {
                {StartPoint.topLeft,    new Point { X = 0,              Y = 0                            }  },
                {StartPoint.topRight,   new Point { X = input.Count(),  Y = 0                            }  },
                {StartPoint.bottomRight,new Point { X = input.Count(),  Y = input[0].Count()             }  },
                {StartPoint.bottomLeft, new Point { X = 0,              Y = input[0].Count()             }  }
            };
            //convert enum to starting position
            var coords = pointConvertion[point];

            int height = input.Length;
            int width = input[0].Length;

            if (dir == Direction.clockwise)
                while(true)
                {
                    Point oldcoords = coords;
                    //right
                    while (coords.X+1 < width && visitedTable[coords.Y][coords.X+1] == false)
                    {
                        yield return retrieveElement(input, visitedTable, new Point { X = coords.X, Y = coords.Y });
                        coords.X++;
                    }
                    //down
                    while (coords.Y+1 < height && visitedTable[coords.Y+1][coords.X] == false)
                    {
                        yield return retrieveElement(input, visitedTable, new Point { X = coords.X, Y = coords.Y });
                        coords.Y++;
                    }
                    //left
                    while (coords.X-1 >= 0 && visitedTable[coords.Y][coords.X-1] == false)
                    {
                        yield return retrieveElement(input, visitedTable, new Point { X = coords.X, Y = coords.Y });
                        coords.X--;
                    }
                    //up
                    while (coords.Y-1 >= 0 && visitedTable[coords.Y-1][coords.X] == false)
                    {
                        yield return retrieveElement(input, visitedTable, new Point { X = coords.X, Y = coords.Y });
                        coords.Y--;
                    }
                    //if it couldnt move, the current block is the last one
                    if (coords == oldcoords)
                    {
                        yield return retrieveElement(input, visitedTable, new Point { X = coords.X, Y = coords.Y });
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                while (true)
                {
                    Point oldcoords = coords;
                    //left
                    while (coords.X - 1 >= 0 && visitedTable[coords.Y][coords.X - 1] == false)
                    {
                        yield return retrieveElement(input, visitedTable, new Point { X = coords.X, Y = coords.Y });
                        coords.X--;
                    }
                    //down
                    while (coords.Y + 1 < height && visitedTable[coords.Y + 1][coords.X] == false)
                    {
                        yield return retrieveElement(input, visitedTable, new Point { X = coords.X, Y = coords.Y });
                        coords.Y++;
                    }
                    //right
                    while (coords.X + 1 < width && visitedTable[coords.Y][coords.X + 1] == false)
                    {
                        yield return retrieveElement(input, visitedTable, new Point { X = coords.X, Y = coords.Y });
                        coords.X++;
                    }
                    //up
                    while (coords.Y - 1 >= 0 && visitedTable[coords.Y - 1][coords.X] == false)
                    {
                        yield return retrieveElement(input, visitedTable, new Point { X = coords.X, Y = coords.Y });
                        coords.Y--;
                    }
                    //if it couldnt move, the current block is the last one
                    if (coords == oldcoords)
                    {
                        yield return retrieveElement(input, visitedTable, new Point { X = coords.X, Y = coords.Y });
                        break;
                    }
                }
        }

        public static TSource retrieveElement<TSource>(TSource[][] matrix,bool[][] tableref,Point location)
        {
            tableref[location.Y][location.X] = true;
            return matrix[location.Y][location.X];
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @t3chb0t oh I see. Deleted my comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issues

- There're a lot of repetitions in your code. This is not easily maintainable.
- The paths are hardcoded
- You cannot easily add new paths
- The casing for public APIs is wrong

## Recommendations

In order optimize it and to unfold this matrix you should start by encapsulating various logics into their own methods. This will allow you to reuse them without copying the code and makes the algorithm clearer.

The first obvious thing are the movements. Let's create a few methods for them:

```
private static Point MoveRight(Point point)
{
    return new Point(point.Row, point.Column + 1);
}

private static Point MoveDown(Point point)
{
    return new Point(point.Row + 1, point.Column);
}

private static Point MoveLeft(Point point)
{
    return new Point(point.Row, point.Column - 1);
}

private static Point MoveUp(Point point)
{
    return new Point(point.Row - 1, point.Column);
}
```

Ok, we can move in each direction now. Notice that I've change the properties of the point to make it easier to understand:

```
public struct Point
{
    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        Row = x;
        Column = y;
    }
    public int Row { get; }
    public int Column { get; }
}
```

We need also an enum for the directions. You already have one but let's fix the naming that should be PascalCase for public APIs:

```
enum UnfoldDirection
{ 
    Clockwise,
    Counterclockwise,
}
```

Finally we can re-write the algorithm for the unfold.

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Unfold<TSource>(this TSource[][] values, UnfoldDirection direction, StartPoint start)
{
    var maxRow = values.Length - 1;
    var maxColumn = values[0].Length - 1;

    var current = new Dictionary<StartPoint, Point>
    {
        [StartPoint.TopLeft] = new Point(0, 0),
        [StartPoint.TopRight] = new Point(0, maxColumn),
        [StartPoint.BottomLeft] = new Point(maxRow, 0),
        [StartPoint.BottomRight] = new Point(maxRow, maxColumn),
    }[start];

    // I'm not proud of this dictionary. 
    // Each path deserves its own object and should be encapsulated in a class.
    // It would be easier to search for it based on those two enums
    // rather then "ToString" everything.
    var path = new Dictionary<string, Func<Point, Point>[]>
    {
        [UnfoldDirection.Clockwise.ToString() + StartPoint.TopLeft.ToString()] = new Func<Point, Point>[] { MoveRight, MoveDown, MoveLeft, MoveUp },
        [UnfoldDirection.Clockwise.ToString() + StartPoint.TopRight.ToString()] = new Func<Point, Point>[] { MoveDown, MoveLeft, MoveUp, MoveRight },
        [UnfoldDirection.Clockwise.ToString() + StartPoint.BottomRight.ToString()] = new Func<Point, Point>[] { MoveLeft, MoveUp, MoveRight, MoveDown },
        [UnfoldDirection.Clockwise.ToString() + StartPoint.BottomLeft.ToString()] = new Func<Point, Point>[] { MoveUp, MoveRight, MoveDown, MoveLeft },
        [UnfoldDirection.Counterclockwise.ToString() + StartPoint.TopLeft.ToString()] = new Func<Point, Point>[] { MoveDown, MoveRight, MoveUp, MoveLeft },
        [UnfoldDirection.Counterclockwise.ToString() + StartPoint.BottomLeft.ToString()] = new Func<Point, Point>[] { MoveRight, MoveUp, MoveLeft, MoveDown },
        [UnfoldDirection.Counterclockwise.ToString() + StartPoint.BottomRight.ToString()] = new Func<Point, Point>[] { MoveUp, MoveLeft, MoveDown, MoveRight },
        [UnfoldDirection.Counterclockwise.ToString() + StartPoint.TopRight.ToString()] = new Func<Point, Point>[] { MoveLeft, MoveDown, MoveRight, MoveUp },
    }[direction.ToString() + start.ToString()];

    var moved = true;
    var visited = new HashSet<Point>(new PointComparer());

    var inRange = new Func<Point, bool>(p => p.Row >= 0 && p.Row <= maxRow && p.Column >= 0 && p.Column <= maxColumn);

    // Starting corner.
    yield return values[current.Row][current.Column];
    visited.Add(current);

    // This is the new heart of the Unfold.
    // It loops through the movements as long as there are unvisited points.
    // Each movement is repeated as long as 
    // it's within bounds of the array or unvisited points.

    do
    {
        moved = false;
        foreach (var move in path)
        {
            var next = move(current);
            while (inRange(next) && visited.Add(next))
            {
                moved = true;
                current = next;
                next = move(current);
                yield return values[current.Row][current.Column];
            }
        }
    } while (moved);
}
```

But how does it work now? The new `MoveX` methods allow us to define the order of movements. We have two. You can have more or them to start at different corners and various paths.

We also need a starting point that lies outside the array because the first move will move it inside the array.

We also check if we already visited a point that I track in a `HashSet<Point>` to know when to change the direction. You could have some other bounding checking but I thought a `HashSet` is an easy quick start.

To know if a point is already in the `HashSet` I created a new comparer:

```
class PointComparer : IEqualityComparer<Point>
{
    public bool Equals(Point left, Point right)
    {
        return left.Row == right.Row && left.Column == right.Column;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Point point)
    {
        int hash = 23;
        hash = hash * 31 + point.Row.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 31 + point.Column.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }
}
```

*Helper*

```
public static string Print(this IEnumerable<int> values, string separator = " ")
{
    return string.Join(separator, values);
}
```

With all this you can visit the points in the specified order:

```
int[][] matrix = new int[][]
{
    new int[] {01,02,03,04,05,06},
    new int[] {07,08,09,10,11,12},
    new int[] {13,14,15,16,17,18},
    new int[] {19,20,21,22,23,24}
};

matrix.Unfold(UnfoldDirection.Clockwise, StartPoint.TopLeft).Print().Dump("Clockwise TopLeft 1 2");
matrix.Unfold(UnfoldDirection.Clockwise, StartPoint.TopRight).Print().Dump("Clockwise TopRight 6 5");
matrix.Unfold(UnfoldDirection.Clockwise, StartPoint.BottomLeft).Print().Dump("Clockwise BottomLeft 19 13");
matrix.Unfold(UnfoldDirection.Clockwise, StartPoint.BottomRight).Print().Dump("Clockwise BottomRight 24 23");

matrix.Unfold(UnfoldDirection.Counterclockwise, StartPoint.TopLeft).Print().Dump("Counterclockwise TopLeft 1 7");
matrix.Unfold(UnfoldDirection.Counterclockwise, StartPoint.TopRight).Print().Dump("Counterclockwise TopRight 6 5");
matrix.Unfold(UnfoldDirection.Counterclockwise, StartPoint.BottomLeft).Print().Dump("Counterclockwise BottomLeft 19 20");
matrix.Unfold(UnfoldDirection.Counterclockwise, StartPoint.BottomRight).Print().Dump("Counterclockwise BottomRight 24 18");
```

*Dump() is LINQPads method.*

Results:

```
Clockwise TopLeft 1 2

1 2 3 4 5 6 12 18 24 23 22 21 20 19 13 7 8 9 10 11 17 16 15 14 


Clockwise TopRight 6 5

6 12 18 24 23 22 21 20 19 13 7 1 2 3 4 5 11 17 16 15 14 8 9 10 


Clockwise BottomLeft 19 13

19 13 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 12 18 24 23 22 21 20 14 8 9 10 11 17 16 15 


Clockwise BottomRight 24 23

24 23 22 21 20 19 13 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 12 18 17 16 15 14 8 9 10 11 


Counterclockwise TopLeft 1 7

1 7 13 19 20 21 22 23 24 18 12 6 5 4 3 2 8 14 15 16 17 11 10 9 


Counterclockwise TopRight 6 5

6 5 4 3 2 1 7 13 19 20 21 22 23 24 18 12 11 10 9 8 14 15 16 17 


Counterclockwise BottomLeft 19 20

19 20 21 22 23 24 18 12 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 13 14 15 16 17 11 10 9 8 


Counterclockwise BottomRight 24 18

24 18 12 6 5 4 3 2 1 7 13 19 20 21 22 23 17 11 10 9 8 14 15 16
```

Comment: Thank you alot for this review, dont you think my boolean array would be more memory efficient tho? I feel like the hashset is overkill, is there a solution that doesn't require checking boundaries?

Comment: @downrep_nation there could be, this was the just quickest way for me to write it. How big are your arrays? Premature optimization isn't a good thing. But I'll try to rewrite it without the hashset.

Comment: @downrep_nation well, whether you use a boolean array or a hashset I don't think it makes a big difference unless you have hundreds of millions of items.

Comment: they could be any size, but reasonable. No 1000x1000 monsters

Comment: @downrep_nation if so then I would not care about the memory, a hashset look up is super fast and easier to do and maintain I think, then an additionalal array and more indicies. At this size it's a matter of taste and preference, I would say.

Comment: also your methods aren't generic anymore, but thankfully thats a quick fix

Comment: @downrep_nation oh, yes, you're right, there's no reason for it to be only a matrix of ints, this should be generic like yours

Comment: @downrep_nation I've fixed it to be generic again.

Comment: And the starting position logic is gone, what do you think about my method of setting it?

Comment: @downrep_nation I've added the missing feature and other paths. Your code crashes already at `UnfoldDirection.Clockwise, StartPoint.BottomLeft` ;-(

Comment: you are correct! I forgot the -1

this answer is very complete now, thank you!